Will DNF also upgrade my installation of PostgreSQL 16?
I have just installed PostgreSQL 16 in Fedora 40 with the following command as per this page:
dnf install postgresql-server postgresql-contrib

According to the main PostgreSQL roadmap, version 17 is expected to arrive next month (September 2024).
Will dnf update automatically and forcibly upgrade PostgreSQL to version 17?
How will I know that all the tables and functions will continue to be read correctly?
